# Unity ,C# :How should i go about using UI Buttons to toggle between follow target? I tried few things and im losing my marbles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton

First time poster here

So, what im trying to achieve is:
I have gameobjects instantiated into the scene, every object has a follow target script attached
i want to change targets on runtime by alternating tags via two (im planning to add more) UiButtons.
everything is in 2d if that makes any difference.

I tried:
-Having two seperate functions for each target and calling those in UiButtons,obviously it wont work since those functions have to be inside update function to work, and i cant figure out if there is a way to disable one follow function while the other is active, and vice versa.

-Creating separate  scripts for each follow command, and toggling different target scripts (while disabling the other one) via ...scripts, couldnt figure it out either.

-And now im trying to call functions that will change the target tag..still no luck

What am I doing wrong? is it because the strings i call, are changed locally in FollowEnemy() and FollowPlayer() functions?
Is there a way to change main tag value?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


    
    private GameObject[] targets;
    private Transform targetedEnemy;
    public string currentTarget;


    
    void Update()
    {
        Follow();
    }

    public void Follow()
    {
        
        Debug.Log(currentTarget);
        targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(currentTarget);
            targetedEnemy = targets[Random.Range(0, targets.Length)].transform;

            float followSpeed = 2f * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetedEnemy.position, followSpeed);
        
    }
    public void FollowPlayer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Following Player!");
        currentTarget = "Player";
    }

    public void FollowEnemy()
    {
        Debug.Log("Following Enemy!");
        currentTarget = "Boss";
    }
}
```

Is there even a way to do this?

Im really sorry for stupid question, im a begginer and im still getting lost while doing a project on my own.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is

```
targetedEnemy = targets[Random.Range(0, targets.Length)].transform;
```

this changes target every frame! You will never follow any target but switch between targets continuously which will just barely jitter around.

Also using `FindGameObjectsWithTag` every frame is quite redundant and expensive as well. (Also you are missing a class definition wrapping your code)

I would do the following

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string PLAYER_TAG = "Player";
    private const string ENEMY_TAG = "Boss";

    [SerializeField] private float followSpeed = 2f;

    // Target we are currently following 
    private Transform currentTarget;
    // Target Tag we are using to find targets as fallback
    private string currentTargetTag;
   
    private void Update()
    {
        // Is there currently no target?
        // could also be true if the target we previously followed was destroyed
        if(!currentTarget)
        {
            // is a target Tag set?
            // if not we do nothing as we don't have a target and also no tag to find one 
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentTargetTag)) return;

            // otherwise find objects by tag ONCE
            var targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(currentTargetTag);
            // and pick a random target ONCE
            currentTarget = targets.Length == 0 ? null : targets[Random.Range(0, targets.Length)].transform;

            // if there was no target found do nothing further
            if(!currentTarget) return;
        }

        // otherwise continue to follow the same target 
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, currentTarget.position, followSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
        
    public void FollowPlayer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Following Player!");
        // [optional] only force new random target if tag actually changed
        if(currentTargetTag != PLAYER_TAG)
        {
            // All you need to do here is store the new tag
            currentTargetTag = PLAYER_TAG;
            // and reset the target => Update will pick a new random target using the new tag
            currentTarget = null;
        }
    }

    public void FollowEnemy()
    {
        Debug.Log("Following Enemy!");
        if(currentTargetTag != ENEMY_TAG)
        {
            currentTargetTag = ENEMY_TAG;
            currentTarget = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG , it never occured to me that the way im tracking the targets is wrong. Thank You. Looks like using someone snippet without fully understanding it will eventually bite me in the rear. Also, i am aware that class is missing i deleted it when writing this post, i thought that it wont be needed, idk why i did that. I will try to figure out how Your code works and work with that. Thank You again.